# Is there any way to make dictionary key,value pairs to tuple?

Tags: python

I need to convert this dictionary:
`{'A': 0, 'B': 1290, 'C': 515, 'D': 600}`

Into this test case:
`(A : 0) - (B : 1290) - (C : 515) - (D : 600)`

This is how I derive my dictionary

```
    def stock_list(list_of_art, list_of_cat):
        new_dictionary = {}
        numbers = []
        for character in list_of_cat:
            if character not in new_dictionary:
                new_dictionary[character] = 0
        for word in list_of_art:
            first_element = word[0][0]
            for number in word:
                if number.isdigit():
                    numbers.append(number)
            make_str = "".join(numbers)
            numbers = []
            if first_element in new_dictionary:
                new_dictionary[first_element] += int(make_str)
        return new_dictionary
```

This is a sample call

```
stock_list(["BBAR 150", "CDXE 515", "BKWR 250", "BTSQ 890", "DRTY 600"],["A","B","C","D"])
```

Comment: `list(yourdict.items())`

Comment: but output should be like that (A : 0) - (B : 1290) - (C : 515) - (D : 600) with hypens and semi colons but what you mean is correct.

Comment: your test case is neither a tuple nor a list. Are you sure it shouldn't be a string?

Comment: You said to tuple. I converted it to tuple. What you want isn't a tuple, at all. Go over your question and delete everything that isn't true. Tell us exactly what you want and what you have. Ask us the proper question. Put everything that's code in some kind of code format block. Clean up the grammar while you're there.

Comment: I completely changed your question. If you feel like it is wrong, click edit and roll it back. You should change the title. Maybe something like "Convert Dictionary To Nonstandard Test Case Format"

Comment: @OneMadGypsy https://www.codewars.com/kata/54dc6f5a224c26032800005c/train/python here's the question did i understand the question bad?

Comment: "For the lists L and M of example you have to return the **string**"

Comment: After you posted the Kata I went and banged it out. I can give you one hint about your code ~ it's way too long and trying too hard. All of the shortest answers, including mine, were about 7 lines long. Special packages or never-ending one-liners were not needed. It's just 7 simple lines.

Comment: Can you tell me how you implement i didn't know other better way to do it.

Comment: I could tell you everything about it, but then you might as well forget about the Kata, because you would just be posting my solution. Here's the best I can do for you ~ use 1 loop, and there should only be 2 or 3 lines in that loop. Don't feel bad though, a bunch of the answers to this were ridiculous ~ like the programmer is trying to build a whole app out of this one little task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the keys and values of your dictionary, and format them into a string.

```py
d  = {'A': 0, 'B': 1290, 'C': 515, 'D': 600}

print(" - ".join(f'({k} : {v})' for k,v in d.items()))
```

`#(A : 0) - (B : 1290) - (C : 515) - (D : 600)`